# i have greedy and dijkstra algorithms with the same distance. My question is which distance to choose, B to C or B to D

Tags: java, algorithm, pseudocode, dijkstra, greedy

The problem I marked in the picture is choosing the shortest path for the greedy and Dijkstra algorithms, now I'm confused because there are 2 identical paths, namely B to C and B to D. Which path will be chosen because as far as I know the greedy algorithm compares the smallest numbers or solves the problem step by step. Thank you for helping :)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z4US.png)

I hope paths B to C or B to D can be completed

Comment: This depends on the implementation ofcourse... Greedy algorithm is very wide describtion for a set of algorithms. 
For path finding indeed the greedy algorithm would chose always the path with lowest weight, for equeal weights it will depend on the implimentation. There is no sure answer for this.

Comment: BFS looks for shortest paths to every node in the graph. There is no ambiguity for the example you give. The shortest path from A to C is 5, and the shortest path from A to D is 5. They will both be found, as they are about different target nodes. No problem.

Comment: oh so the path is the same as the greedy algorithm node, which depends on the implementation and depends on the user